# Applying the Pauling's electronegativity when the ionisation enthalpy and electron gain enthalpy of an element are given

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronegativity

I came across the following problem while practicing some exercises on inorganic chemistry:

> If the ionization enthalpy and electron gain enthalpy of an element are **275** and **86** $Kcal mol^{-1}$ respectively, then the electronegativity (in $KJ mol^{-1}$) of the element on the **Pauling scale** is?

I know this is rather, a formula based question but I was really confused about this. According to the formula for pauling's scale which is,

$|\chi_A - \chi_B|= 0.208\sqrt{\Delta E}$ :

[image]

The question doesn't even seem right as it only mentions a single element while the formula talks about difference of electronegativities and considers A and B as:

$\ce{A2 + B2 -> A-B}$ where $\chi_{A}, \chi_B$ are the electronegativities of A and B respectively.

How do I work this out?  I thought of simply taking $\Delta E$ as the difference of the given Ionisation enthalpy and the electron gain enthalpy. And that got me the answer. But thats just for the sake of getting the answer. I can't get the point behind this.

Comment: What about using Mulliken scale and then using the relation between Pauling and Mulliken scale?

Comment: @Rishi Can you please elaborate more on this and post an answer? I actually tried applying it but I haven't got the desired output and the different formulae on different sources just increase the confusion.

Comment: You are right, there was a relation in one of my textbooks but it is knowhere to be seen on the web, wiki, chemlibre etc. It was $$\mathrm{\chi_{Pauling} =\frac{IP+E.A.}{2.8}}$$ If I find a reliable reference I will post an answer.[Here EN(P)=EN(M)/1.4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Atkins' Physical Chemistry,

> The electronegativity is a parameter introduced by Linus Pauling as a measure of the
> power of an atom to attract electrons to itself when it is part of a compound. Pauling used valence-bond arguments to suggest that an appropriate numerical scale of electronegativities could be defined in terms of bond dissociation energies, $\Delta$, in electron volts and proposed that the difference in electronegativities could be expressed as
> $$\mathrm{|\chi_A - \chi_B| = 0.102 ({\Delta_{A-B} -\frac{1}{2} .(\Delta_{A-A} + \Delta_{B-B}}))^{\frac{1}{2}} \tag{1}}$$
> Electronegativities based on this definition are called Pauling electronegativities.

> The spectroscopist Robert Mulliken proposed an alternative definition of electronegativity.
> He argued that an element is likely to be highly electronegative if it has
> a high ionization energy (so it will not release electrons readily) and a high electron affinity (so it is energetically favorable to acquire electrons). The Mulliken electronegativity scale is therefore based on the definition $$\mathrm{\chi_M = \frac{1}{2} (I+ E_{Ea})  \tag{2}}$$ where $\mathrm{I}$ is the ionization energy of the element and $\mathrm{E_{ea}}$ is its electron affinity (both in electron-volts).
> The Mulliken and Pauling scales are approximately
> in line with each other. A reasonably reliable conversion between the two is
> $$\mathrm{\chi_P = 1.35{\chi_M}^{\frac{1}{2}}-1.37 \tag{3}}$$

Converting electron-volts to $\pu{kJ mol-1}$ Eq-(1) converts to
$$\mathrm{|\chi_A - \chi_B| = 0.0103 ({\Delta_{A-B} -\frac{1}{2} .(\Delta_{A-A} + \Delta_{B-B}}))^{\frac{1}{2}} \tag{4}}$$
and Eq-(2) converts to
$$\mathrm{\chi_M = \frac{1}{192.97} (I+ E_{Ea}) \tag{5}}$$

**Reference**

[Atkins' Physical Chemistry: Eleventh Edition , Oxford University Press](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/atkins-physical-chemistry-9780198769866?cc=gb&lang=en&%5D).